# How do I use Scriptaculous's Effect.Morph to turn off a class?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Scriptaculous's Effect.Morph can take a CSS class and apply it over a period of time.  I have a div which expands when a button is clicked, so it uses Effect.Morph to apply an `.expanded` class.

Now I'd like to remove the `.expanded` class on a second click, toggling the div closed again.  How can I invoke Effect.Morph to do that?

Comment: you should sumbit the path here, or a link on the scriptaculous page. I hit the same problem and a path would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says this about [Effect.Morph](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-morph):

> This effect changes the CSS properties
>   of an element.

So you would need to call it again, specifying the initial CSS properties so your div can revert back to its initial state, for example (again, from the docs):

```
<div id="morph_demo" style="background:#cccccc; width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="$('morph_demo').morph('background:#00ff00; width:300px;'); return false;">Click me for a demo!</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="$('morph_demo').morph('background:#cccccc; width:100px;'); return false;" >Reset the demo!</a></li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you could use Prototype to [remove the class altogether](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/removeClassName):

```
$('yourDivId').removeClassName('yourClassId');
```

Scriptaculous depends on [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/), in case you weren't aware, so the second option is a viable one.

Finally, you can [set the style](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/setStyle) to nothing (I think):

```
$('yourDivId').setStyle(null);
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the answer is that it can't be done with a Morph effect (without restating all of the styles of the element without the class applied, which isn't very DRY).  I've extended Effect.Morph to do what I want, though, so I'll push a patch up to Scriptaculous.

Comment: Did you ever push that patch? How do you get it to work? I tried calling $('element_id').morph('class_name') as if it were toggle, but it seems to be always adding the class name.

Comment: I hadn't.  I've issued a pull request now: https://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/pull/26